# How to track mouse enter event while mouse is pressed c# visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, mouseevent

I try to achieve the following: 
While mouse pressed-> if mouse enters panel, color changes 
When mouse up -> the panels won't change on mouse enter.

--Problem: when mouse down pressed, mouse enter event not reacting

How do I solve this?

```cs
//for all panels in the menu
private void walletpanel0_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( mouseDown && previousPanel != (Panel)sender)
        {
            Panel p = (Panel)sender;
            p.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 26, 41, 56);

            previousPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 44, 62, 73);

            previousPanel = p;
         }
     }

private void walletpanel0_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        //to select the panel when clicked on it
        if (previousPanel != (Panel)sender)
        {
            Panel p = (Panel)sender;
            p.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 26, 41, 56);

            previousPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 44, 62, 73);

            previousPanel = p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it fire the `MouseDown Event` when you place a breakpoint inside of mousedown event..?

Comment: MouseEnter always fires *before* MouseDown.  And cannot fire afterwards since MouseDown sets the Capture property to true.  Use MouseMove, it also fires when you hover a different panel thanks to the capture.  Use GetChildAtPoint() to get a reference to the panel.  And use the MouseCaptureChanged event to detect it got interrupted.

Comment: It doesn't fire the 'MouseDown' event when I place a breakpoint inside the function no@MethodMan

Comment: Well the `MouseMove` event also freezes when the mouse is down. I tried, and read on microsoft post. So with the solution to use the `MouseCaptureChanged` event I could detect the capture state. Though, when the mouse is down, I still can't use `MouseMove` event because the mouse is still down. I tried using  the `ReleaseMouseCapture()`function, though doesn't apply on Panels apparently.@HansPassant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `MouseEnter`, `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` events don't fire while a mouse button is being pressed. Once the button is released, the subscribed events fire if the mouse movements triggered it while the button was down.

The basic problem is that when the `MouseDown` event occurs on a `Control`, that `Control` "captures" the mouse and doesn't release it until the button is released, which means that movement events are not received by other `Controls`.

Assuming that all your `Panels` subscribe it, the following event handler should help you:

```
private void Panels_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.None)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;

        if (control.Capture)
            control.Capture = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Though I just integrated the same type of funtion in    MouseMove and I see it also doesn't react just as the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my answer, see if it can help you now.

Comment: Many Thanks! :D Exactly what i was looking for!  hoped I could vote up the post, but I would need 15 reputation for it.